# C# alpha-beta pruning with reference

Tags: c#, list, reference, alpha-beta-pruning

So here is the problem. I'm working on a combat-simulator for an AI based game. The AI should calculate the best move for him when the enemy makes his best move against every move.

My team has X units with 5 possible moves and my opponent has Y units with 5 possible moves. X and Y > 0
using alpha-beta pruning we want to generate each possible outcome and take the best one out in the end. The problem is the fact that we save each outcome into a situation, this situation stores lists but the lists contain references to the objects stored, this makes them save their moves into the same situation (all 5 moves of 1 unit)

Imagine 2 of our units and one of theirs. We create a situation and add one unit with 1 of the 5 directions to it. Then for our second unit we add one direction, then for the enemy unit. Now we got the end situation we want to save this. Then from the situation we had in OUR second unit (so without the enemy unit) we want to add a different move for the enemy to the situation and save that new situation if it was better. But since C# uses references for lists this situation is the situation with the other enemy move included aswell.

Code is a bit large but I'm really stuck here so I'd hope if anyone has some spare time to help me out with ideas to fix this.

```
    public Situation RecursiveMaxTree(List<SimAnt> undone, int index, bool[,] positions, Situation situation)
    {
        SimAnt front = undone[index];
        int max = situation.Max;
        List<SimAnt> bestmoves = new List<SimAnt>();

        int frontY = front.position.Y;
        int frontX = front.position.X;

        if (!front.isEnemy() && undone[index + 1].isEnemy())//cutoff activated----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            foreach (Direction direction in directions)
            {
                int newX = GameState.WrapHorizonal(frontX + direction.toVector().X);
                int newY = GameState.WrapVertical(frontY + direction.toVector().Y);
                if (!positions[newX, newY] && map.isNotWater(newX, newY))
                {
                    //add the updated ant to the new allAnts list
                    positions[newX, newY] = true;
                    List<SimAnt> newallAnts = situation.GetList;
                    Friend newant = new Friend(newX, newY);
                    newant.direction = direction;
                    newallAnts.Add(newant);

                    Situation current = RecursiveMinTree(undone, index + 1, positions, new Situation(newallAnts, max));//geeft min van alle enemy options
                    positions[newX, newY] = false;
                    if (current.Max > max)
                    {
                        max = current.Max;
                        bestmoves = current.GetList;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else //max-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            foreach (Direction direction in directions)
            {
                int newX = GameState.WrapHorizonal(frontX + direction.toVector().X);
                int newY = GameState.WrapVertical(frontY + direction.toVector().Y);
                if (!positions[newX, newY] && map.isNotWater(newX, newY))
                {
                    //add the updated ant to the new allAnts list
                    positions[newX, newY] = true;
                    List<SimAnt> newallAnts = situation.GetList.Clone();
                    Friend newant = new Friend(newX, newY);
                    newant.direction = direction;
                    newallAnts.Add(newant);

                    Situation current = RecursiveMaxTree(undone, index + 1, positions, new Situation(newallAnts, max));//geeft min van alle enemy options
                    positions[newX, newY] = false;
                    if (current.Max > max)
                    {
                        max = current.Max;
                        bestmoves = current.GetList;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new Situation(bestmoves, max);
    }

    Situation RecursiveMinTree(List<SimAnt> undone, int index, bool[,] positions, Situation situation)
    {
        SimAnt front = undone[index];
        int max = situation.Max;

        int frontY = front.position.Y;
        int frontX = front.position.X;

        int currentmin = 100;

        foreach (Direction direction in directions)
        {
            int newX = GameState.WrapHorizonal(frontX + direction.toVector().X);
            int newY = GameState.WrapVertical(frontY + direction.toVector().Y);
            if (!positions[newX, newY] && map.isNotWater(newX, newY))
            {
                //add the updated ant to the new allAnts list                    
                List<SimAnt> newallAnts = situation.GetList;
                Foe newant = new Foe(newX, newY);
                newallAnts.Add(newant);
                if (index >= undone.Count - 1)
                {
                    return new Situation(situation.GetList, CalculateBattleValue(situation.GetList));
                }
                else
                {
                    positions[newX, newY] = true;
                    Situation current = RecursiveMinTree(undone, index + 1, positions, new Situation(newallAnts, max));//geeft min van alle enemy options
                    positions[newX, newY] = false;
                    if (current.Max < max)
                        return current;
                    else if (current.Max < currentmin)
                    {
                        currentmin = current.Max;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new Situation(situation.GetList, currentmin);
    }

class Situation
{
    public Situation(List<SimAnt> ants, int max)
    {
        this.max = max;
        this.ants = ants;
    }
    List<SimAnt> ants;
    int max;

    public List<SimAnt> GetList
    { get { return ants; } }

    public int Max
    { get { return max; } }
}
```

Kind regards, me